# Mathematics topics required to work on time series analysis

Tags: time-series, mathematical-statistics

I will soon start working with time series data. Which topics in mathematics should I cover? I am planning to go all the way, and I do not shy away from challenging topics.

P.S. I have already gotten introductory class level calculus, linear algebra and diff equations, prob/stats covered.

Answer (score 3):

I think more than mathematics you'll need to have a solid understanding of statistics. I'd recommend you study regression, statistical inference as you'll definitely need to know topics in these subjects well.

Answer (score 0):

It's a vaste field of study. This book has a excellent coverage of time series theory [Time Series Analysis](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387759586), you should try it.

Comment: This would be more helpful if you expanded it to say what the coverage of that book is and why you recommend it.